# How to find the annual evolution rate for each firm in my data table?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

So I have a data table of 5000 firms, each firm is assigned a numerical value ("id") which is 1 for the first firm, 2 for the second ...

Here is my table with only the profit variable :
|id   | year | profit
|:----| :----| :----|
|1    |2001  |-0.4
|1    |2002  |-0.89
|2    |2001  |1.89
|2    |2002  |2.79

Each firm is expressed twice, one line specifies the data in 2001 and the second in 2002 (the "id" value being the same on both lines because it is the same firm one year apart).

How to calculate the annual rate of change of each firm ("id") between 2001 and 2002 ?

I'm really new to R and I don't see where to start? Separate the 2001 and 2002 data?
I did this :
 `years <- sort(unique(group$year))years`

And I also found this on the internet but with no success :

```
library(dplyr)
res <-
  group %>%
  arrange(id,year) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(evol_rate = ("group$year$2002" / lag("group$year$2001") - 1) * 100)  %>%
  ungroup()
```

Thank you very much

Comment: can you give a reproducible example of your data table (group) ?

Comment: I added an example of my data table, hope you can see it good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've written, I take it that you want to calculate the formula for ROC for the profit values of 2001 and 2002:

`ROC=(current_value​/previous_value − 1) ∗ 100`

To accomplish this, I suggest `tidyr::pivot_wider()` which reshapes your dataframe from long to wide format (see: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html#pivoting).

**Code:**

```r
require(tidyr)
require(dplyr)

id <- sort(rep(seq(1,250, 1), 2))
year <- rep(seq(2001, 2002, 1), 500)
value <- sample(500:2000, 500)

df <- data.frame(id, year, value)

head(df, 10)
#>    id year value
#> 1   1 2001   856
#> 2   1 2002  1850
#> 3   2 2001  1687
#> 4   2 2002  1902
#> 5   3 2001  1728
#> 6   3 2002  1773
#> 7   4 2001   691
#> 8   4 2002  1691
#> 9   5 2001  1368
#> 10  5 2002   893

df_wide <- df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = year,
              names_prefix = "profit_",
              values_from = value,
              values_fn = mean)

res <- df_wide %>%
  mutate(evol_rate = (profit_2002/profit_2001-1)*100) %>%
  round(2)

head(res, 10)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>       id profit_2001 profit_2002 evol_rate
#>    <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>
#>  1     1         856        1850    116.  
#>  2     2        1687        1902     12.7 
#>  3     3        1728        1773      2.6 
#>  4     4         691        1691    145.  
#>  5     5        1368         893    -34.7 
#>  6     6         883         516    -41.6 
#>  7     7        1280        1649     28.8 
#>  8     8        1579        1383    -12.4 
#>  9     9        1907        1626    -14.7 
#> 10    10        1227        1134     -7.58
```

Comment: The first part works, now I have the first line of firm 1 with profit_2001 and the second one there is profit_2002. But in my column evol_rate there is only NA. should I add "na.omit" in the mutate function ?

Comment: Cheers! And good luck with your analysis :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without reshaping your data into a wide format you can use

```
library(tidyverse)

id <- sort(rep(seq(1,250, 1), 2))
year <- rep(seq(2001, 2002, 1), 500)
value <- sample(500:2000, 500)

df <- data.frame(id, year, value)

df %>% head(n = 10)
#>    id year value
#> 1   1 2001  1173
#> 2   1 2002  1648
#> 3   2 2001  1560
#> 4   2 2002  1091
#> 5   3 2001  1736
#> 6   3 2002   667
#> 7   4 2001  1840
#> 8   4 2002  1202
#> 9   5 2001  1597
#> 10  5 2002  1797

new_df <- df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(ROC = ((value / lag(value) - 1) * 100))

new_df %>% head(n = 10)
#> # A tibble: 10 × 4
#> # Groups:   id [5]
#>       id  year value   ROC
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#>  1     1  2001  1173  NA  
#>  2     1  2002  1648  40.5
#>  3     2  2001  1560  NA  
#>  4     2  2002  1091 -30.1
#>  5     3  2001  1736  NA  
#>  6     3  2002   667 -61.6
#>  7     4  2001  1840  NA  
#>  8     4  2002  1202 -34.7
#>  9     5  2001  1597  NA  
#> 10     5  2002  1797  12.5
```

This groups the data by `id` and then uses `lag` to compare the current year to the year prior

Comment: Hello, I tried this way but I have this message : Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `ROC = (group20$mktcap) - lag(group20$mktcap)`.
x `ROC` must be size 2 or 1, not 8000.
i The error occurred in group 1: group20$id = 1.

Comment: Did you try using `mutate(ROC = mktcap - lag(mktcap))`?

Comment: I tried : library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

id <- sort(rep(seq(1,250, 1), 2))
year <- rep(seq(2002, 2001, 1), 500)
value <- sample(500:2000, 500)

df <- data.frame(group20$id, group20$year, group20$mktcap)
df %>% head(n = 10)

new_df <- df %>%
  group_by(group20$id)
  mutate(ROC = group20$mktcap - lag(group20$mktcap))
new_df %>% head(n = 10)

Comment: Now I have this message : Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Comment: Your example code mixes up `value` with `mktcap` as well as `df` with `group20` so I can't replicate your code. Your error is probably that within dplyr verbs like group_by() and mutate() you are using `group20$id` rather than `id` and `group20$mktcap` rather than `mktcap`. dplyr verbs work different than standard R https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Comment: thank you I just added the "attach" command and it now it works !